# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x1'

Tags: python

I got an error,AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x1'.
In test.py I wrote

```
    # coding= utf_8
    import libraries as libraries
    import DataCleaning
    import datamod as md

    num = 1

    if num == 1:
        df = libraries.pd.read_csv('aaa.csv')
    datas = DataCleaning.DataCleaning(df)
    datas.cleaning(media)

 datas = md.x1(datas)
```

In datamod.py I wrote

```
 # coding= utf_8

from test import datas
class datamod:
    def x1(datas):
     datas.extraction('func1','1')
    def x2(datas):
     datas.extraction('func2', '2')
```

I really cannot understand why this error happen.I import my module(datamod.py) ,I worote it(import datamod as md) in  test.py .How can I fix this error?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: Your `datamod` _module_ only defines one name: `datamod`. You can access that in "test.py" with `md.datamod`. Now do you see how to refer to the `x1` name of the `datamod` class?

Comment: Why do "test.py" and "datamod.py" import each other? That's known as a circular import, and is generally not a good thing to do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thx,ur comments.I wrote ur code like 
dm = dm.datamod()
dm.x1(datas)

But I got same error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x1'

Comment: @PM2Ring　thx,ur comments.I wrote ur code like　    md.datamod.x1(datas)

 But I got same error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x1'

Comment: it should be `dm = dm.datamod() dm.x1(datas`